# Strange background texture in Android Material Design

Tags: material-design, user-experience

I have experience in developing an Android Application but I'm new in Material Design. This one seems basic but I can't find any articles on the internet that tackles about this concept.

I want to know how the cube-like texture on the background is occured. Is this one can be achieved through theme? If yes, I'm pretty sure that it's only for API 21. Also, I want to know how to achieve this kind of ui in pre-lollipop devices.

Here is the sample image:

[image]